# Which is an appropriate term for school management to use while referring to students in official letters sent to their parents?

Tags: word-choice

I have seen "all wards", "all children" and even "all scholars" commonly used in letters sent to parents by schools. For example:

> Dear parents, all the **wards** are required to be present in the auditorium by 9:30 AM.

I would like to know what is the standard term used to refer to school children in **this context**.

Comment: In British English, I think we would use 'all pupils'. 'Wards' seems an odd choice, as it usually means a child who is under the guardianship of someone who is not their parent. Maybe the word is used differently in Indian English.

Comment: I feel like *all children* is the most neutral, just because it's clear what you're talking about - otherwise it's going to depend on the language that's typically used by that school or in that region. Like @KateBunting says, *pupils* would be typical here, maybe *students* (more modern and suitable for older children) but maybe not elsewhere. *Scholars* sounds a little pretentious to me, but some schools like to play up to that kind of thing!

Answer (score 2):

In British English, it depends on the pupils' ages.  Particularly if they are at primary school (up to the age of 11), "all children" might be the most likely choice where the context is clear.  "All pupils" would also be correct.

For pupils at secondary school (11+), "all students" (which older Brits consider an Americanism when used for under-16s) is now more widely used, but "all pupils" would also be considered correct.